# If condition for when an element moves off left-side of window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect when an element, that a jQuery plugin makes draggable, moves off the left edge of the window.

I have a if condition in the on drag custom-event. The event fires on drag, but the alert inside the condition doesn't fire when the element moves off the left edge of the screen.

This leads me to think there is something wrong with my if-condition.

To me, this reads going left and when anything greater than 0% is off the left edge of the screen.

```
$('#tabViewWindow').pep({
    axis:'x',
    useCSSTranslation:false,
    drag:function(ev, obj){
    if(obj.dx>0 && obj.$el.offset().left>$(window).width()*0){
        obj.velocityQueue = new Array(5);
        alert("left and moving towards off screen");
        return false;
    }
    handleOpacity(ev, obj)
    },
 });
 function handleOpacity(ev, obj){
    var opacity = 1 - (parseInt(obj.$el.css('left'))/$(window).width());
    obj.$el.css('opacity', opacity);
 }
```

Comment: Can you please show where `obj` is assigned?

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 0?

Comment: @Asad updated the question to show my full js / jQuery code.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy to represent 0% of the width of the window. When that amount or more is over the edge.

Comment: Wouldn't 0 itself suffice then?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Yes, yes it would. Except something is wrong with my logic because either should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking the elements' bounding box as it has been computed for the page the element is on by the browser, using `element.getBoundingClientRect().left` (this might be identical to jQuery's offset.left) and simply checking if it's less than 0. If so, your element is at least partially off screen. Then, as second check, if `element.getBoundingClientRect().left + element.getBoundingClientRect().width` is smaller than 0, your element is entirely off-screen.

Comment: I don't want to know when it is entirely off screen. I want to know when it is barley off screen, the moment it is off window even the slightest bit. I also updated my code to show all of my code / implementation.

Comment: in which case `.left < 0` is all you need.

Comment: I am still confused. What element.left ? Can you put exactly what I should have in my if statement in your answer?

Comment: you write "the alert inside the condition doesn't fire when the element moves off the left edge of the screen". That element. It has a bounding box "left" value, and if that value is below 0, that element has gone past the left edge of the screen.